# Practices in integrating client-server communication with .net core MVC web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I've been using knockout.js handle client-server communication, but now want to know if my way is correct and how it works in other frameworks, like Angular2 or React when they are integrated to MVC web app.

Assume we have a model for a game

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double SkillRating { get; set; }
    public List<Attendance> GameAttendanceHistory { get; set; }
    public DateTime MemberSince { get; set; }
}
```

but when we want to make a chat system, some of the properties aren't necessary for the view, so the viewmodel of the user would be like this

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public UserViewModel(User user)
    {
        Id = user.Id;
        Name = user.Name;
    }
    //For guest users
    public UserViewModel()
    {
        Id = 0;
        Name = "Guest";
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and there are some UI models

```
//One chat channel. Users can open several channels at once.
public class BoardViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MessageToPost { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

//Message to be posted to each channel. Messages will be stored in SQL database.
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    public int PostById { get; set; }
    public string PostByName { get; set; }
}
```

and finally, controller passes a viewmodel

```
public class ChatUIViewModel
{
    public UserViewModel CurrentUser { get; set; }
    //List of all boards to which the user belonging
    public List<BoardViewModel> Boards { get; set; }
}
```

to the view and I let knockout.mapping parse the json of the data to create the viewmodel to use. If the user join a new channel, post or get a message, then the client will request the data of the target board via SignalR hub, or notified the message from hub and annex it to the DOM.

Here my concern is necessity of giving a data to the view upon action call.

Because the client anyway communicates with the server for updating their status, I doubt that I need to let the controller passes the list of the boards when the user request the action.

Clients can also request the data when the page is loaded via WebAPI, SignalR or some other method, and then it doesn't have to parse the json data to create a viewmodel. Plus, if I place such a function which the returns the data on cloud it would be good for reducing the load of my server instance. Having this assumption on the right track?

Also, I guess in other frameworks it's a fundamental approach that clients post/get all what they need to/from the server, but not sure. Could someone explain the difference between the three frameworks mentioned above in terms of client-server communication in this case of chat app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cut a long story short:

- **You should have the master model on you server.**
- **In the case a new client connects to the server, first the clients should make a GET for the acutal state of the model.**
- **After that the server informs the clients about changes.**

I did once a project where I used signalr also for the first get, because the client can also call methods with signalr on the server. There are some developers which think this is not a good solution but I do not understand the argumentation

Sample:

Imaging you have simple tic-tac-toe game (Fields A1/A2/A3/B1/B2/B3) for two player (Player X and player O). First both player have to connect to this playfiled. After both clients are connected you should inform one player (for Example Palyer X) that you can start. The other client see only that the other player is on turn.  Player X then clicks on field A1. As a result you send this information to the server like playerMove(gameId, playerId, fieldId). The server validates this and if valid he sends an event to both players playerMoved(gameId, playerId, fieldId). As a result of this both clients will draw the X in A1. The server sends also an event to the client X that client O is on turn, and an event to client O that he is on turn.
All the model stuff is running on the server.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the ideas and a clear example. So do you think it's a good way to let server give the whole model to clients when it passes the viewdata to them? Also, how about the other frameworks?

Comment: @K.Makino You need only to send the model what the client uses in initial state. I did it once in a WPF application. I see no reason why it should work with other frameworks. Or what the reasons for this question?

Comment: Well I think that's why I need to truncate some properties and methods for the viewmodel. My point was if it's also necessary for the controller to get the list of actual records of boards, chat messages and users from database when it passes the data to the view, or just giving the information of the class structure to it. According to your explanation it seems okay to let clients have only the structure of the viewmodels.

Comment: Also, for your question, one day I came up with refurbish my whole project with single page application and saw that react or angular is more flexible and useful for SPA. I didn't know well about them, but found an article that stated differences between knockout and them. And then I wanted to ask here what's the difference when it comes to MVC application where views need to receive a data from corresponding controllers.

Comment: I see no reason why it should not work the same. Your model should be free from visual stuff. How something will look like only the client is responsible. With the sentences "model is on server" i do not mean that you pass the whole data from server to client. For example make pocos dto. Also it is for example not necassary that you send all posts from server to client. Maybe you send only the last 10 and additional to that you add a pagging mechanisme.

Comment: If you like talk about spa with angular or other framework its also the same. Once I did a bigger application with angular where the whole master model was on server. I can describe you the application directly in a chat. Its to big for here.